# Increment with remainder not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, whatsapp

In my script the computer clicks through contact tabs in WhatsApp Web and for each checks whether the person is online or not. This is done with a loop, which starts again when contact number 16 is reached. Anyhow, the loop doesn't work and the variable 'i' doesn't increase. This is strange, since if I replace selectContact(`${i}`) by console.log, the increment works. Maybe the `${}` prevents the i from updating?

```
var i = 1
setInterval(function () {
    selectContact(`${i}`)

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("O90ur")[0] !== undefined) {
    var online = document.getElementsByClassName("O90ur")[0].innerHTML
        if (online == "online") {
        console.log(`${i}`)};
                        }
    i = i % 16 + 1
}, 1000);
```

Here is the code for selectContact, if the issue should lie within here.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

contacts = [];
chat_div = [];

function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function getChatname(){
    $("#pane-side > div > div > div").find("._2FBdJ >    div._25Ooe").each(function(){ 
        contacts.push($(this).text());
        chat_div.push($(this));
    })  
}

function selectContact(name){
    getChatname()
    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
        if (name.toUpperCase() === contacts[i].toUpperCase()){
             triggerMouseEvent(chat_div[i][0],"mousedown")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you have `var i = 1` global then in `selectContact(name)`, you have `for` loop using `i` too and it increases. If this is the case then change `i` to `j` in `selectContanct` should fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed out the `var` statement declaring `i` in your for loop, meaning it overwrites your global `i`.

```
function selectContact(name){
    getChatname()
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
        if (name.toUpperCase() === contacts[i].toUpperCase()){
             triggerMouseEvent(chat_div[i][0],"mousedown")
        }
    }
}
```